# How to edit a value in localStorage with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, local-storage

I am working on a simple "Green Light, Red light" game using Angular, and I am storing players with their score and maxScore using localStorage.

I can already read each property from the array stored in the localStorage, but now I am stuck on modifying those values once I click a button.

This is the test array I am currently working with:

```
[{"name":"test1","score":3,"maxScore":8},{"name":"test2","score":10,"maxScore":22}]
```

This array is stored with a single key named "players", so it is an array of players.

My component looks like this:

**game.component.ts**

```
export class GameComponentComponent implements OnInit {
  highScoreLS: number = this.getHighScoreData();
  scoreLS: number = this.getScoreData();

  highScore: number = 0;
  score: number = 0;
  state: string = 'RUN';

  faArrowRightFromBracket = faArrowRightFromBracket;
  faShoePrints = faShoePrints;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  addPoint() {
    this.score++;
    if (this.score > this.highScore) {
      this.highScore = this.score;
    }
    this.changeHighScore();
    this.changeScore();
  }

  removePoint() {
    this.score--;
    if (this.score < 0) {
      this.score = 0;
    }
    this.changeHighScore();
    this.changeScore();
  }

  changeState() {
    if (this.state === 'RUN') {
      this.state = 'PAUSE';
    } else {
      this.state = 'RUN';
    }
  }

  getScoreData() {
    let localStorageItem = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('players') || '[]');
    let item = localStorageItem.find(
      (item: { name: string }) => item.name === 'test1'
    );
    let sc = item.score;
    return sc;
  }

  getHighScoreData() {
    let localStorageItem = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('players') || '[]');
    let item = localStorageItem.find(
      (item: { name: string }) => item.name === 'test1'
    );
    let hs = item.maxScore;
    return hs;
  }

  changeHighScore() {
    let localStorageItem = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('players') || '[]');
    let item = localStorageItem.find(
      (item: { name: string }) => item.name === 'test1'
    );
    item.maxScore = this.highScore;
    localStorage.setItem('players', JSON.stringify(item));
  }

  changeScore() {
    let localStorageItem = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('players') || '[]');
    let item = localStorageItem.find(
      (item: { name: string }) => item.name === 'test1'
    );
    item.score = this.score;
    localStorage.setItem('players', JSON.stringify(item));
  }
}
```

And the html looks like this:

**game.component.html**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Hi! </h2>
    <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink=""
      ><fa-icon [icon]="faArrowRightFromBracket"></fa-icon
    ></a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container flex vh-100">
  <div class="row m-3">
    <h3>HIGH SCORE: {{ highScoreLS }}</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="row m-3">
    <div class="card p-3">
      <h3>{{ state }}</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row m-3">
    <h3>SCORE: {{ scoreLS }}</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="row m-3">
    <div class="col">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success" (click)="addPoint()">
        <fa-icon [icon]="faShoePrints"></fa-icon>
        Left
      </button>
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success" (click)="removePoint()">
        Right
        <fa-icon [icon]="faShoePrints"></fa-icon>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is, when I click the button to add or remove a point, it deletes the whole array of players, and creates a new one like the following:

```
{"name":"test1","score":0,"maxScore":1}
```

I have been working for a couple of days with localStorage so I do not know exactly what I am missing or what I am doing wrong.
My idea is to edit those values, **score** and **maxScore**, but I can't figure it out how.

**EDIT**
The first time I click on add a point, it edits only the maxScore, but once. The next time I click, it gives me this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: localStorageItem.find is not a function
    at GameComponentComponent.changeScore (game-component.component.ts:83:33)
    at GameComponentComponent.addPoint (game-component.component.ts:34:10)
```

Comment: The problem is here: `localStorage.setItem('players', JSON.stringify(item));` you're overwriting the array with the single item you changed. You need `localStorage.setItem('players', JSON.stringify(localStorageItem));` instead.

Comment: If you're getting an error like this, the first step is to do `console.log(localStorageItem)`. You'd have gotten an object instead of an array, which would've pointed you to the mistake. You can also check the contents of localStorage in the dev tools (F12).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling localStorage.setItem with just the single item and not the whole array so every subsequent "finds" you're trying will fail.

Try this instead:

```
localStorage.setItem('players', JSON.stringify(localStorageItem));
```

Though I have to say, there's loads of duplicate code in just that one component. You should read some articles on data structures and state management.

Comment: First, thanks for the answer, it worked perfectly.
Second, yes, I know there is a lot of code that can be extracted into a single function, it is in my mind to refactor everything once everything works fine, but thanks for your suggestion, really appreciated.

Comment: This is a typo type error, please don't post answers to these. SO is more like wikipedia, it's not a chat forum.